# How to change font color of string in excel cell with condition "Greater than or equal to" using python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

I have an excel file with data stored as strings in different columns. I want to apply the condition >= and change the text color to red if the condition is met in that cell of the column without changing the header background color.

**Data:** https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArCp0UbnlDouglYGkM83sQtckagM?e=e5nUgn

**Condition:** If any value in column *Qt._For_1s* is greater than or equal to 900.0 then the font color of that specific value should turn into Red (without messing with the header colors) else can either be green or stay the same black with white background and saved as xls file.

**Note:** These column values are saved as strings because they are needed like that.
I have tried several conditional formats but could not solve my specific problem.

```
def highlight_Qt(row):
    ret=["" for _ in row.index]
    if (row.Qt._For_1s) >= str(900.0):  # also tried without str() no results
        ret[row.index.get_loc("Qt._For_1s")]="background-color: Red"
    return ret

data.style.apply(highlight_Qt, axis=1).to_excel("Data.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
```

This messes up the header color and not giving the required results.
I am looking this up in StackOverflow posts over the last 5 days but could not find any post related to this specific condition.

Comment: Your comparison is wrong because it will use string comparison. Better to convert the cell's value to a number and then see if this is > 900.

Comment: @jmcnamara any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to open your file with openpyxl and format it

```
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Open the workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('file_name.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Get the columns name
ColNames = {}
Current  = 0
for COL in ws.iter_cols(1, ws.max_column):
    ColNames[COL[0].value] = Current
    Current += 1


## Set the font color
ft = Font(color="00FF0000")

## Acces the cells
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    cell = row[ColNames['Qt._For_1s']]
    try:
        if int(cell.value) > 900:
            cell.font = ft
    except:
        pass
    
wb.save("styled.xlsx")
```

Comment: It is giving me an error as  `keyError: 'Qt._For_1s'`  and arrow is pointed on the row where  `cell=row[Colnames['Qt._For_1s]] ` ... I checked the Colnames and it is enumerating correctly all column names

Comment: It does not give any error but it does not change the font color for column's value > 900.

Comment: Can you please run it and check why. I have python 3.6

Comment: Are you sure that a new file named "styled.xlsx" is not created with the font formatted ?

Comment: Yes, I ran the code 2-3 times. no color change in the styled.xlsx file

Comment: cell values are strings tho. maybe that is why?

Comment: it gives `ValueErroe: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Qt._For_1s'`

Comment: No, it does not because the column 'Qt._For_1s' is the string column. there are intergers/floats in this column but it gets saved as string in the program hence '>' does not work on string cells. That is the problem I am facing